# Coroutine combined Job is not completed

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

When getting a job from launch, the job complete properly

```
fun testCoroutineScope() = runBlocking {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    val job = scope.launch {
        delay(200)
        println("Job done")
    }
    delay(500)
    println(job.isCompleted)
}
```

Output:

```
Job done
true
```

But this is not the case when you combine your own job.

```
fun testCoroutineScope() = runBlocking {
        var job = Job()
        val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + job)
        scope.launch {
            delay(200)
            println("Job done")
        }
        delay(500)
        println(job.isCompleted)
}
```

Output:

```
Job done
false
```

Looks like the job is never completed. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scope.launch` creates a new Job. When you do `Dispatchers.Default + job`, you are not passing your job to the scope. You are creating a new `CoroutineContext` that combines elements of the `job` and `Dispatchers.Default`. The literal job object itself is not passed to the new context.

Comment: But why the job is not completed? I can still cancel with the pass in job which means they have some kind of connection, but then why is it still active?

Comment: It is the parent Job of the other Job. It’s not complete because you can still add more children to it.

Comment: So does that mean, in my example, if I don't cancel the parent job deliberately, it will never become completed/canceled?

Comment: @PandaWorld Yep, it is still active. If you want to manually complete a job it should be an implementation of [CompletableJob](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-completable-job/index.html) and you call `complete()` on it.